# SQL query on 3 tables reusing a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here 3 tables where I want to write a SQL query to get values on Table3 from Table1 and Table2

```
Table1           
| ID  | NAME  |
+-----+-------+
| 111 | ALPHA |
| 222 | BRAVO |
+-----+-------+

Table2
| NAME_RESULT | STEP_ID | STEP_NAME | STEP_TYPE | STEP_PARENT |
+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 111         | aaa     |  R1       |  step2    |  5cf        |
| 222         | bbb     |  R2       |  step2    |  e7b        |
| 333         | ccc     |  R2       |  step2    |  3ac        | 
| 555         | e4a     |  C4       |  step10   |  51f        |
+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+

Table2 we find on NAME_RESULT = 222 and STEP_ID = bbb --> STEP_PARENT = e7b Next reusing the previous STEP_ID from first STEP_PARENT values to get new STEP_PARENT :

| NAME_RESULT | STEP_ID | STEP_NAME  | STEP_TYPE | STEP_PARENT|
+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+
| 111         | e7b     |  Measure R |  step2    |  89d       |
| 777         | 3ac     |  Measure R |  step2    |  5fc       |
+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Also with the next query on Table2 we found on STEP_ID = e7b --> STEP_PARENT = 89d

```
Table3 on t3.IDM = t2.STEP_PARENT = 89d :

| IDM | MEAS  |
+-----+-------+
| eee | 10.1  |
+-----+-------+
| 89d | 12.2  |
| 5fc | 7.3   |
+-----+-------+    We find MEAS = 12.2
```

1) First query :

```
select * from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.NAME_RESULT
where t2.STEP_NAME = 'R2' and t2.STEP_TYPE = 'step2' and 
t1.NAME = 'BRAVO'
```

--> Result should be STEP_ID = bbb

2) Second query :

```
select * from Table2 t2 where t2.STEP_PARENT = STEP_ID
```

--> Result should be STEP_ID = e7b

2) Third query :

```
select * from Table2 t2 where t2.STEP_ID = STEP_PARENT
```

--> Result should be STEP_PARENT = 89d

3) Last query :

```
select * from Table3 t3 inner join t2 on t2.STEP_PARENT = t3.IDM
```

--> MEAS value should be = 12.2

Hope It will be more explicit so tell me what and if possible how have all in one query

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you show the full expected output?

Comment: How can result of 2nd query can be `STEP_ID = e7b`? Please explain.

Comment: On a first query on Table2 I get STEP_ID = bbb and then STEP_PARENT = e7b - On a next query (always on Table2) I reuse the previous found STEP_ID from first STEP_PARENT values to get new STEP_PARENT = 89d because we are relative keys between column STEP_ID and STEP_PARENT on this table too

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are actually looking for. Why is 'BRAVO' in your first query? As an example or do you want results for 'BRAVO' only? Why is 'R2' in that query? Why is 'step2' in the query? Is the task for the query: "Find the MEAS for the parent of BRAVO|R2|step2"?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner - Is the task for the query: "Find the MEAS for the parent of BRAVO|R2|step2"? --> Yes exactly, values used are simplified for this example because the initial DB come from electronics component measurement with XML export facilities so the structure is complex with some long Hexadecimal keys values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think this question is quite confusing. But hopefully, this is the query you are looking for.

```
select
    t3.meas
from
    table3 t3
inner join
    table2 t2a
on t3.idm = t2a.step_parent
inner join
    table2 t2b
on t2a.step_id = t2b.step_parent
inner join
    table1 t1
on t2b.name_result = t1.id
where
    t1.name = 'BRAVO'
and t2b.step_name = 'R2'
and t2b.step_type = 'step2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right then this should work.

```
select t3.MEAS from Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t21 on t1.ID = t21.NAME_RESULT
inner join Table2 t22 on t21.STEP_PARENT  = t22.STEP_ID 
inner join Table3 t3 on t3.IDM = t22.STEP_PARENT
where t21.STEP_NAME = 'R2' and t21.STEP_TYPE = 'step2' and 
t1.NAME = 'BRAVO'
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

```
select meas
from table3
where idm =
(
  select step_parent
  from table2
  where step_id =
  (
    select step_parent
    from table2
    where name_result =
    (
      select id
      from table1
      where name = 'BRAVO'
    )
    and step_name = 'R2' 
    and step_type = 'step2'
  )
);
```

You may have to replace some `=` with `IN` in case there can be more than one entry in the data set.

Comment: Firstly, you should learn to use proper joins. This method is going to cause you performance issues when working with larger datasets. Secondly, there are no values in step_parent on table2 that match with step_id on the same table. Therefore this query could never return any values. But, I understand where you got this association from in the weird wording of the question.

Comment: @Matthew Hart: Thank you for this advice. I learnt proper joins some twentyfive years ago :-) Sometimes a query gets clearer - especially for beginners - when it represents the structure of thought. With a BRAVO record we get to the R2/step2 record, from that to its parent, from that to the IDM. A good optimizer should't make a worse execution plan for this by the way. (But you are right, MySQL's optimizer might.)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake on the second part, I was misreading the data with table 2 being split into 2 sections.

Comment: @Matthew Hart: Yes that is confusing and had me puzzled at first, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have no access to the distant server this week but I will try them ASAP with data frame in R and sqldf library on my MAC to verify the result - It should be OK - Still thank for your help

Comment: It's OK after testing on R - Thank you